# Toolbar Command for "Set Startup Projects"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, when I right click on a solution, there is an option for `Set Startup Projects...`.

[image: Set Startup Projects Menu Screenshot]

I use this when I need to have more than one Startup Project selected (I wish the dropdown in the Standard Toolbar was a checkbox list).

I would like to add this to a toolbar (for quicker access).  But I can't find the command for it.

I went and looked in the Solution context menu command list, and I don't see it in there.

I also looked the commands in the Keyboard Shortcuts section with the text "Startup", and I don't see it in there.  There was `Debug.StartupProjects` (which is the drop down option already on the standard toolbar) and `Debug.StartupProjectProperties` (which gives the properties window for the project that is set as the startup project.)

**Is there a way to get a keyboard shortcut / toolbar shortcut to this "Set Startup Properties..." command?**

Answer (score 0):

The command for keyboard binding is **Project.SetasStartupProject**.

To add it to a toolbar you can find this command in the Project category:

[image]

But to open the startup project selection dialog you need to activate the Solution Explorer window and select the root solution node before invoking this command.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to control debugging via DTE, you can first use command `File.OpenFile` to open a source file within the project you wish to launch, then use command `Project.SetasStartupProject` to set the startup project.

After that you can use `Debug.Start` and `Debug.StopDebugging` commands to start/stop debugging as necessary.